# Prestashop - blockuserinfo position & translation

Tags: smarty, prestashop

I have an issue with blockuserinfo module. It displays in place which is not the best according to the layout. So i wanted to move it to different place. SO i did following thing - from blockuserinfo.tpl I copied element:

```
{if $logged}
<a href="{$link->getPageLink('my-account', true)}" title="{l s='View my customer account' mod='blockuserinfo'}" class="account" rel="nofollow"><span>{$cookie->customer_firstname} {$cookie->customer_lastname}</span></a>
<a href="{$link->getPageLink('index', true, NULL, "mylogout")}" title="{l s='Log me out' mod='blockuserinfo'}" title="{l s='Log out' mod='blockuserinfo'}" class="logout" rel="nofollow">{l s='Log out' mod='blockuserinfo'}</a>
  {else}
<a href="{$link->getPageLink('my-account', true)}" title="{l s='Login to your customer account' mod='blockuserinfo'}" class="login" rel="nofollow">{l s='Log in' mod='blockuserinfo'}</a>
  {/if}
```

and pasted into header.tpl to the place I wanted to have it. It appears and works BUT there is huge problem with translation - after pasting it into header.tpl data from blockuserinfo changed into english and I cannot change the language of those texts (even after switching the lang). In admin panel > module translation there is MISSING variable for login and logout under blockuserinfo.

How to repare it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translations in PS for module is working according to the module name. Like if you check your code, you will have static strings like

```
{l s='View my customer account' mod='blockuserinfo'}
```

The mod='blockuserinfo' says to the PS translation system to get the translation for that module line. So what you need to do is to remove parts of mod='blockuserinfo' from all the texts you have in the copied code at header.tpl file. Please note that all texts should be like

```
{l s='View my customer account'}
```

After that go to admin panel, and then translation section and then go to front end translation. Find header.tpl section and enter the translations again for the texts you need.

Again note that if you move a text from a file or a module, then its translation will not work, because, while fetching the translated text, PS looks to the translations according to the file name, or module name.

Hopefully this will help you.

Thank you